# Difference between `git rm --cached` and `git update-index --assume-unchanged`?

Tags: git, caching, git-rm

I do not understand the difference between `git rm --cached` and `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.

I'm aware that `git rm --cached  <file>` will remove a file from the staging area.

And, I know that `git update-index  --assume-unchanged <file>` also does this.

I've also seen both commands offered as suggestions to similar questions here on SO.

Is there another affect of either of these two commands that makes them different?

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Comment: sorry, was afk for a day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The command

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

is used to untrack files in a Git branch.  This command will remove the `file` from the staging area and *also* will remove the file from the repository next time you commit.

The command

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

will also make the `file` disappear from the staging area.  However, this command is different because it tells Git to only *temporarily* ignore any changes made to the `file`.  So when you commit the file it will remain a part of the repository assuming it were already there.  When you want Git to see the changes made to the `file` again, you can run this:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

This will return the file to the staging area, if it were there when you ran `assume-unchanged` earlier.

Here is a [link](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/03/06/ignoring-doesnt-remove-a-file.html) for `git rm --cached`, and here is a [link](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html) for `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.

Comment: Unfortunate wording: `git update-index --assume-unchanged` won't *remove* the file's entry from the index but will rather stop Git checking this entry against the matching file on the filesystem. I beleive that you possibly just have some wording sloppiness here but it's an important one ;-) To possibly make my point more clear, the index initially (that is, right after `git read-tree`) "contains" all the files from the tree-ish which had just been read in. Hence making Git "turn a blind eye" to an index entry does not equal actually *removing* it.

Comment: Hm.  I see your point and it's an important one.  thank you.   Question:  so, if I forget to do the `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>` command, then does that mean that it will continue to ignore my file until I remember to do so?  If so, that makes me a bit nervous about using this command.

Comment: Also, in the `git rm --help` page, I didn't see anything mentioned about removing the file from the repository.  Do you have a source to support this, @TimBiegeleisen?

Comment: Updated my answer.  `git update-index --assume-unchanged` is like a temporary mask on the index.  It will stay in effect until you turn it off.