# Git --skip-worktree not working as intended

Tags: git

I know we have lot of discussions on this out here but those aren't solving my issue. So placing my question here.

I want to untrack some files from being shown as modified while doing git status, and I tried different options as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git/936290#936290)

ex.
I want to untrack test.txt file and I tried like these:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree test.txt
```

Immediately, when I do git status, still it is showing as modified. Is there something wrong here?
Also, I tried adding this to **.git/info/exclude** file but no luck. Can anyone please throw some ideas here?

Comment: Tracked file, and you want to remove it? Would `git rm —cached` do? https://stackoverflow.com/q/33428702/989920

Comment: I think you are mixing up concepts. Untracking a file means removing it from the repo. To do that you'd `git rm --cached` and then commit the change. This means that the file will be **removed** for other developers who use the same repo (assuming you pushed the commit). After having untracked the file, if you do not want it to show up in `git status`, you can add it to the `.gitignore` file. If you instead want `test.txt` file to be kept in the repo, but want to make modifications to it without those showing up in `git status`, that's when you can use the `skip-worktree` command...

Comment: But you should **not** both untrack the file **and** issue the `skip-worktree` command that you mention in your question.

Comment: _"Immediately, when I do git status, still it is showing as modified."_ - that should not happen, unless the file is already staged - is it?

Comment: @Alderath, yes you're correct. Exactly I want skip-worktree as I want to setup some personal .gitignore kind here.
If I add it in .gitignore, it is not showing up but it would affect all the developers when I push it. I don't want that. I just want to exclude some files from showing up on git status in my machine only.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - git rm -cached is removing the file itself and it will remove from repo too if I push the changes. So, I chose skiptree as I am in need of that kind.

Comment: `—cached` should stop the file from being deleted.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, Thanks for your time. Will try again and see.

Answer (score 2):

The files must have already been in the staging area before you flagged them. You must first remove them from the staging area to exclude them.

First, run '**git reset**' to remove the files from staging.

Then, run the **'git update-index'** command to flag the files as Skip-Worktree/Assume-Unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove it from git status would be:

```
git reset -- afileBeginModified
```

But untracking completely would be a combination of:

```
git rm --cached -- afile_I_Dont_want_to_see_ever
echo afile_I_Dont_want_to_see_ever > .gitignore
```

Comment: git rm -cached is removing the file itself and it will remove from repo too if I push the changes. I am in need of something that will exclude a file from showing up in status irrespective of that file already there in repo or not. Thanks.

Comment: @SCSVEL Did you try assume-unchanged? (as I documented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23806990/6309)

Comment: yeah. I did try assume-unchanged too but no luck.

Comment: @SCSVEL Then read http://xyproblem.info/, and adopt a different aproach. For instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48449663/6309

Comment: Thanks for your time. I will try again from start and see with different approach.